# MySQL performance issue with bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, performance, prepared-statement

I have a strange performance issue with a specific query only when I am binding parameters.

Here is my code:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT count(item_id) AS count FROM MyView WHERE active = 1 AND context_id = 5 AND snapshot_id = 24');
$time_start = microtime_float();
$statement->execute();
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time1 = round($time_end - $time_start, 4);
$result = $statement->fetch()['count'];

$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT count(item_id) AS count FROM MyView WHERE active = :filter_active AND context_id = :filter_context_id AND snapshot_id = :filter_snapshot_id');
$statement->bindValue('filter_active', 1, 2);
$statement->bindValue('filter_context_id', 5, 2);
$statement->bindValue('filter_snapshot_id', 24, 2);
$time_start = microtime_float();
$statement->execute();
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time2 = round($time_end - $time_start, 4);
$result = $statement->fetch()['count'];
enter code here
```

Time results:

```
time1 = 0.79 sec
time2 = 31.50 sec
```

Could someone explain me why we get this huge performance difference?

Thanks

EDIT & Solution:
The parameter type was wrong. I should have used PDO::PARAM_INT instead.
Note that if I don't specify the param type has got very poor performance.

Comment: a) what exactly does microtime_float() do and how does it differ from microtime(true)? b) `PDO::PARAM_STR = 2`, while `PDO::PARAM_INT = 1` - why do you bind your integer values as string? c) how does your table structure look like, how much data is in it and what indizes do you use?

Comment: Binding as string would be my first guess as to the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys! it's the binding type which was wrong. Using PDO::PARAM_INT get me an execution time of 0.0005 sec!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, how many things are wrong with the question *and* the comments!

- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- we need to see the datatypes, indexes, and engine (at least).
- For faster running, have an index on `(active, context_id, snapshot_id)` in any order.
- Instead of `count(item_id)`, say `count(*)`.  The former is when you need to test `item_id` for being not `NULL`.
- `WHERE int_col = 123` and `WHERE int_col = "123"` are virtually identical in performance, and identical in effect.  The one combination that is bad is `WHERE char_col = 123` -- in this case it converts each `char_col` to a number before comparing; this makes indexing useless.
- `0.0005 sec` is very likely to be bogus.  You probably have the Query Cache turned on -- tiny times like this happen when a query was recently run, cached in the QC, then run again.  It is not re-executing the query, but simply pulling the resultset from the QC.
- For 'honest' timing, use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid the QC.  Then run it twice (and take the second timing) to avoid I/O caching.

Comment: Thanks Rick, for your feedback,

Comment: The problem is not from the request itself but the way it is executed through PHP. Same request, 2 execution times very different. The comments solved my issue.

Anyway,
1 - I can't show you the table structure because it's a very complex VIEW
2 - I experienced and the index did not change the performance difference. And by the way, the order of the columns are very important in an index.
3 - Interesting comment
4 - perhaps
5 - I will use this SQL_NO_CACHE option the next time.
Thanks

Comment: `VIEWs` do complicate things -- sometimes the equivalent `SELECT` runs a lot faster.  Binding puts quotes around the numbers, but that _should not_ affect the execution time different you are experiencing.

Comment: In my case the experience shows a huge difference when the binding is done on strings...

Comment: I would like to get to the bottom of this.  Can you display the SQL _after_ binding is finished?  (In both cases.)